# Filtering Pivot Table column

Tags: vba, filter, filtering, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I tried and looked on this forum and Others but I couldn't find the right working code yet.

I want to filter on a pivot table a column with values equal or higher than 10%. 
When I recorded my macro, code was as follow:

```
Sub Macro9()
Macro9 Macro
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$36607").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=0.1" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

This doesn't work but I wanted to launch the macro afterwards.

So I tried other codes, like the following :

```
 Sub FilterPivotTable()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = True

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name of my column").ClearAllFilters

  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Name of my column").PivotFilters. _
Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=">=0.1"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this didn't work either.

Can anyone please help me? 
Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: Apparently, the fact that my field is a calculated one is important. Still don't have an answer though.

Comment: Did you substitute `"Name of my column"` with the actual column name?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was just to hide on Internet the actual name of my column.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found myself an answer to my question.

Since the columns I wanted to filter were values and calculated fields, I actually needed to filter these columns by right-clicking on a cell inside a row value of my PVT. Then, I had to filter by chosing the right value to sort and add my criteria. 
The code when recording a macro is as follow:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Your row name").PivotFilters. _
Add2 Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Your value field"), Value1:=0.1
```

Hope it can help some of you, as I haven't seen an answer to this issue in many forums.

Have a nice day!